# windows location url not working in salesforce 1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have created visual force page using script inside the script I given windows open URL.I am not able to get my url. What did I wrong my code. I ought to display sales force 1.below my vf page code Please can any one help me out.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <h1>Please Wait</h1>
    Redirecting ....
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function navigate()
    {
    if ( (typeof window.parent.sforce != 'undefined') && (window.parent.sforce!=null) ) 
    {
        sforce.one.createRecord(...);
    }
    else 
    {
        window.location='/00Om0000000KPsf?pv0={!Account.Name}&excel=1';
    }
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Refer this SF Article on S1 Navigation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for salesforce one you need to use  `sforce.one.navigateToURL(navigateURL);`

```
var navigateURL = "/00Om0000000KPsf?pv0={!Account.Name}&excel=1";

if((typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null))
{
       sforce.one.navigateToURL(navigateURL);
}
```

More info https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

Comment: thanks for you reply I made some changes my code working fine for me. I change like below:javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL('/00Om0000000KQ8G?pv0={!Account.Name}&excel=1');